# jQuery select all elements with a common class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to handle a click event across a set of links so tried to approach this by adding a secondary class like following:

```
<a href="..." class="foo external">Test 1</a>
<a href="..." class="bar external">Test 2</a>
<a href="..." class="car external">Test 3</a>
<a href="..." class="dar">Don't handle this one</a>
```

Then tried this jquery selector to select the "external" class on links:

```
$('a.external').click(function(e) {
    do something here...
});
```

However this isn't working like I expected. What's the right way to handle this?  Should I just use a wildcard selector like the following or is there a better way?

```
$('[class^="someclass"]').click(function(e) {
 ....
});
```

Comment: How do you "expect" it to work? Everything seems fine...

Comment: By what measure is it not "working?" What are you using to make that determination?  `console.log`, 'alert'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you have is exactly right (though the e probably isn't necessary in `function(e)` in your case).

```
<a href="#1" class="foo external">Test 1</a>
<a href="#2" class="bar external">Test 2</a>
<a href="#3" class="car external">Test 3</a>
<a href="#4" class="dar">Don't handle this one</a>

<script>
    $('a.external').click(function(e) {
        // will print the href in a javascript alert box
        alert( $(this).attr('href') );
    });
</script>
```

As far as I can tell the only possibility is that your `<script>` is actually above your `<a>` tags -- your script can't add the click listeners to the anchors because they wouldn't exist yet.
If so, you'll need to wrap the javascript in `$(document).ready( function(){ /* code here */ });`

Also, no need for the `external` class, just use the "select all absolute anchors, but not the ones linking to my domain" selector: `$('a[href^="http://"]').not('[href^="http://mydomain.com"]')`

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to guess that your issue is that clicking the links actually makes it navigate somewhere? You need to tell the browser to ignore the normal link behavior. Otherwise your click function will run and then it will immediately navigate to the 'href' url. Also make sure this is all wrapped in a ready function.

```
$(function() {
  $('a.external').click(function(e) {
    // Do whatever        

    e.preventDefault();
  });
});
```

Comment: Does `e.preventDefault()` need to go as the last statement or the beginning?

Comment: Doesn't matter as long as it is called before the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

I tried it out in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nE689/1/) and it works.

You have an extra parenthesis on the `click()` function.
Notice have your `function(e)` you have close parenthesis, remove that.

You should end up with this:

```
$('a.external').click(function(e) {
    do something here...
});
```

Comment: Sorry just a typo on my part, in my code the parenthesis are correct. I updated the original question.

Answer (score 0):

try : http://jsfiddle.net/n6JJ3/

```
$('a.external').click(function() {
    jQuery(this).css('background','red');
});​
```

Comment: Please don't just post links to jsFiddle. Post the relevant code as well.